# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1 The file doesn't exist

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb

I'm trying to run gdb on my C program but my debugger shows this on my terminal:

```
> (gdb) file main

Reading symbols from main...done.

> (gdb) run

Starting program: /home/userA/Desktop/test/part4_sent/main 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
The file doesn't exist.
[Inferior 1 (process 10250) exited with code 01]

> (gdb)
```

What's the problem? I have searched the internet but I haven't found anything  to work..

Comment: Does this file actually exist on your system?

Comment: Do you have /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ?

Comment: Yes the file exists, I searched it and it's located in lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.. I don't know why it seems it doesn't exist. Should I change the path or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are produced by GDB:

```
Starting program: /home/userA/Desktop/test/part4_sent/main 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
```

This line is likely produced by your program, and is not something that GDB prints:

```
The file doesn't exist.
```

This line is GDB telling you that your program has exited with error code 1:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 10250) exited with code 01]
```

To verify this theory, you can set breakpoint on `main`, and observe that it is reached.

You can then use `catch syscall exit_group`, which will cause GDB to stop when your program exits, and use GDB `where` command to see why it is exiting. (Does your program require an input file that you are failing to supply?).

Comment: yes, this was the problem. The file doesn't exist line was by my program as I had a netlist. So I put it as an argument on gdb and it worked!